# Python - Tkinter RadioButton If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I've got a radio button which lets me select 0, 1 or 2. The following script prints 0, 1 or 2 in the terminal, but I want it to do 'stuff' depending on what I select.

For example, If I select 0, I want it to do a root.destroy()
If I select 1, I want it to do something else etc.

I thought I'd need to declare a global variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the script.

```
root = Tk()

v = IntVar()
v.set(0)  # set to 0 pics as default. Just looks prettier...

languages = [
    ("0 Pics",0),
    ("1 Pic",1),
    ("2 Pics",2),
]

def ShowChoice():
    world = v.get()
    global world
    print world

Label(root, text="""How many pictures do you have left to scan?""", padx = 15).pack()

for txt, val in languages:
    Radiobutton(root, 
                text=txt,
                padx = 20, 
                variable=v, 
                command=ShowChoice,
                value=val).pack(anchor=W)

mainloop()

Radiobutton(root, 
            text=txt,
            indicatoron = 0,
            width = 20,
            padx = 20, 
            variable=v, 
            command=ShowChoice,
            value=val).pack(anchor=W)


print 'The V get variable is: ' + world()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda to pass your function with argument.

```
for txt, val in languages:
    Radiobutton(root, 
                text=txt,
                padx = 20, 
                variable=v, 
                command=lambda: ShowChoice(root),
                value=val).pack(anchor=W)
```

In the ShowChoice function, just use if/else to do 'stuff' depending on what is selected.
For example.

```
def ShowChoice(root):
    world = v.get()
    if world == 0:
       root.destroy()
```